# Ada manuals: difference between annotated and consolidated

Tags: ada, manuals

what's the difference between the Consolidated Ada Reference Manual 2005 Edition (ISO/IEC 8652:2007(E), Ed. 3) from Springer and the Annotated Ada Reference Manual (ISO/IEC 8652:1995(E)) 2005 Edition? The Annotated Ada Reference Manual is marked as Draft 16. If I understand correctly, the consolidated version is the final version of the annotated one. Am I right?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotated reference manual contains supplementary notes and information about the contents of the reference manual, largely intended to assist compiler implementers.  If you take the [Consolidated Ada Reference Manual](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-TTL.html) and add annotations, you end up with the [Annotated Ada Reference Manual](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05aarm/html/AA-TTL.html). The definitional *reference* text will be identical, the annotations then are commentary upon the content of the reference manual.

Comment: So the consolidated manual is a pretty and final version of the annotated one?

Comment: No. I edited my answer and tried to make the distinction a bit clearer. Think of the RM as a brand new textbook, while the annotated RM is a marked up version of that same textbook--notes in the margins, comments, portions underlined and highlighted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The two references you quote are to different editions. I don't have a printed copy of the AARM, so can't comment on the Draft 16 part. I do have a Springer Ada 2005 Reference Manual ISO/IEC 8652/1995(E) with Technical Corrigendum 1 and Amendment 1. This was released (according to the notes at the top of the back cover) before ISO approval of the "Ada 2005" amendment; I expect yours was released afterward. Probably not a lot of difference.

Manuals could be released once, with Technical Corrigenda and Amendments released later as different documents. That makes it hard to understand. The Consolidated manual has the corrections and amendments included.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same Springer version as you have i.e. Technical Corrigendum 1 and Amendment 1. Inside on the first page, it's written: "Consolidated Ada Reference Manual" — 2005 Edition, The Standard Libraries on the top and at the bottom: 305, 8 November 2006,The standardard Libraries. Also I have obtained from the web the Ada Reference Manual, ISO/IEC 8652:2007(E) Ed. 3 Technical Corrigendum 1 and Amendment 1, Copyright © 2004, 2005, 2006 Ada-Europe. They can be the same document. In addition, I have the bigger AARM with Tech. Corrig. 1 and Amendment 1 (Draft 16) © 2004, 2005 Ada-Europe.